# show website header and footer in the pdf file in datatables

Tags: pdf, header, datatables, footer

I am facing problem when I am trying to add my website's header and website's footer in my pdf file. I can download the pdf file by using datatables default plugin. But in the pdf file I want to show the header and footer of the website in the pdf file.My code is like:

```
"sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
"oTableTools": {
"aButtons": [
{
"sExtends": "pdf",
"bFooter": true
},
{
"sExtends": "print",
"sInfo": "Please press escape when done"
},
{
"sExtends": "csv",
"sButtonText": "Save to CSV",
"bFooter":false                     
}
]
}
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure datatables download plugin was maid in order to work with the whole page. I think it can only work on datatables content. Hope I'm wrong.

Comment: I understood, even I also think so. But is there any option to add two external images with the datatables content?

Comment: By using "sPdfMessage" we can set the test message, but is there any option instead of message image will be visible?

Comment: You can populate a variable with an image tag : `myVar = "<img src='destination/to/my/file.png' alt='myImage' title='myImage'/>"` and then use myVar in datatable as other variables

Comment: I did that but it is showing NaN

Comment: It is showing NaN in your datatables or in downladed file?

Comment: In my downloaded file.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this. I added custom header and footer in my PDF by modifying swf file of datatables. I added a header image and footer text. if you still need any help then ping me.